# Dynamically extendable ladder shape

Tags: visio, shapesheet

My question is two parts, and answers to either would be helpful.

I want to make a Master shape that can be expanded on one axis only. When you expand it the image inside repeats itself. I still want to be able to resize the image proportionally. See the picture for example.

[Discrete extendable ladder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BL9d.png)

The second part of my question is how to restrict this expansion to discrete segments, meaning that the expanded image snaps to the next segment when it gets close enough, but nothing in between. I think I can do this with the BOUND() function, just not sure how.

Comment: Alright,I haven't figured out how to do this completely yet, but I have part of the answer. First, make a fill pattern of a segment of repeating shape. Then fill a rectangle with that fill pattern, adjust, and save it as a mastershape. Use Bound() on the Height of the master in shapesheet to restrict it to the appropriate segments.

Comment: What I still can't get is being able to resize it proportionally, the Fill Pattern won't expand. Also, the bound function only accepts a certain number of arguments, so it can't be infinite. I'd like to figure out how to use programming in BOUND() to make it infinite.